# Read two-dimensional array into arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

How to create `ArrayList<Object> points` based on two-dimensional array `datapoints`?

Anothor question: if `datapoints` is two-dimensional ArrayList, how to read the 1st column into `lat` and the 2nd column into `lon`?

```
public class Cluster {
    private ArrayList<VisitPoint> points;

    public Cluster(List[][] datapoints) {
        Float lat;
        Float lon;
        for (int i=0; i<datapoints.length; i++) {
            lat = datapoints[i][0];
            lon = datapoints[i][1];
            points.add(new VisitPoint(lat,lon));
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<VisitPoint> getVisitPoints() {
        return points;
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the problem ?

Comment: What's `List[][] datapoints`? @AchintyaJha I'm sure you can tell me.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza datapoints is two-dimensional ArrayList ...!!!!

Comment: @AchintyaJha so, I'm sure you can cast an `Object` to `Float` as showed in the code above, or there would be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `List` of `ArrayList`. which is

```
List<List<VisitPoint>> list = new ArrayList<List<VisitPoint>>();
```

ex iteration -

```
for (List<VisitPoint> list2 : list) {
    for (VisitPoint visitPoint : list2) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: It says that 'datapoints' is specified incorrectly. public Cluster(List datapoints) {
  Float lat;
  Float lon;
  for (List<Float> list : datapoints) {
      for (Float visitPoint : list) {
    lat = list.get(0);
    lon = list.get(1);
    points.add(new VisitPoint(lat,lon));
      }
  }
 }